# MySQL Workbench overwrites query tab code

Tags: select, mysql-workbench, right-click

When I right-click a table in MySQL Workbench (version 5.2) Object Browser, choosing "Select Rows - Limit 1000", I expect the result to appear in a *new* tab. Instead, the currently selected query tab has its contents *replaced* with a generated `SELECT` statement. Often, this overwrites SQL code I am in the process of developing. Fortunately, I can use Undo to get it back.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior, that a new tab is opened?

Comment: Getting more used to MySQL Workbench, I have learned to manually create a new window before `select`ing something, but it's a usability nightmare and I don't understand why this behavior was favored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem rectified in newly released Workbench 5.2.39.

Comment: Now there's just a bunch of other deviations from UI standards to get annoyed from. For instance, why doesn't Ctrl+F4 close a tab window?